# Pgfplots and ClassicThesis: two plots side-by-side

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, margins, classicthesis

I always loved the small text width imposed in ClassicThesis, but it is a problem when we have a lot of images/graphs. I would like to have two plots side-by-side in order to gain space (they are not very important plots and I don't want to "waste" and entire page for them). However, also using `\pgfplotsset{small}` they don't fit. I could make them even smaller, but they became unreadable.

Which is the best solution to solve this problem? Enlarge the text width of classic thesis? Use `makebox` in order to ignore the margins? Give up? I would like to obtain the best possible result typographically.

Comment: Ignore margins: big no. The best solution is to place them vertically.  Even if they are not important,  that's about your only option, in my opinion.

Comment: @Alenanno — I mildly disagree when it comes to figures and tables. The function of a small linewidth is better readability — this isn't necessary for two graphs stacked side-by-side. In addition, the overall text becomes easier to read because each page is more dense — there's less page flipping when inspecting the figures.

Comment: @WillRobertson if the graphs are printed side by side,  they become too small to be readable, since the text width is quite narrow as said in the OP.  I think that rather than having that,  stacking them one after the other would be much more preferable to set them side by side ignoring the margins,  which is rather typographically ugly. The figures don't need to span a full page,  still, I'd have to see them to give my definite opinion since currently the information is limited.

Comment: @Alenanno — sure, I don't think you can have a rigid rule here. See my example below for something that I don't think is typographically ugly `:)`

Comment: @Alenanno They are standard pfgplots graphs

Answer (score 2):

For mine similar cases I define new environment named *wide* for which I use macro `adjustwith` from package `changewidth`:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

    \newsavebox\widebox
\newenvironment{wide}%
    {\@parboxrestore%
     \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep}%
                \begin{lrbox}{\widebox}%
                \begin{minipage}{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}%
    }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
      \usebox\widebox}%
      \end{adjustwidth*}
     }
```

Package `calc` is used in calculation ow width of environment and amount of extension of *wide* outside of text width. With `{adjustwidth*}` the extension is always go to outer page border. Example of its use is:

```
\begin{figure}[htb] % or table
    \begin{wide}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Ma wide figure}
\label{fig:wide}
    \end{wide}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly that I did in my thesis, too. One remark: I prefer having the caption *outside* the wide environment.

Answer (score 1):

@Zarko has already posted a good answer for creating a `wide` environment to stack the figures inside. Depending on the exact page layout of the document, for a two-sided I prefer in some cases to use the inside margin as a hard stop:

[image]

This can be done by defining a new `\raggedout` command which calls `\flushleft` on a verso page and `\flushright` on a recto page:

```
% Symmetric ragged commands
\newcommand\IfOddPage{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage\expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\newcommand\raggedout{\IfOddPage\raggedright\raggedleft}
\newcommand\raggedin{\IfOddPage\raggedleft\raggedright}
```

This is then used in the definition of `wide` as follows:

```
\newenvironment{wide}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth}
    \raggedout
}{%
  \end{adjustwidth*}%
}
```

Finally, for some cases you might very well want have some stretchy space between the figures, and using `\hfil` here will put an equal distance between the outside margin and the outside figure as between the two figures themselves. The source of the image above:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{wide}
    \begin{subfigure}
      \psfragfig{PhD/Experiments/Gauss/fig/gauss-vertical}
      \caption{Axial displacement down the centreline.\figlabel{gauss-vertical}}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfil % <= pay attention!
    \begin{subfigure}
      \psfragfig{PhD/Experiments/Gauss/fig/gauss-radial}
      \caption{Radial displacement with a \SI{5}{mm} offset.\figlabel{gauss-radial}}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{wide}
  \caption[
    Magnetic flux density measurements of a cylindrical permanent magnet.
  ]{
    Magnetic flux density measurements of an \maggrade{35} neodymium \diameter\SI{100x30}{mm} cylindrical permanent magnet.
    The origin of the measurements is \SI{5}{mm} from the face of the magnet.
  }
  \figlabel{gauss-meas}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What about decreasing the horizontal space between the two plots? I don't know, I'm still not convinced by the difference in width between the plots and the text. It looks inconsistent, but it's not anyone's fault, I think the conditions in this case make it hard to fit them together in the same line.

Comment: @Alenanno — Oh sure, you could cram them in. But then it looks more crammed in :) The example I chose is for a particular sparse plot as well. As with many decision in typography, there's no definite wrong or wrong — just competing design decision.